# How to implement an eraser in a simple graphics editor?

Tags: ios, graphics, bitmap, uibezierpath

I want to create simple graphics editor on iOS, in which I use bitmap graphics context and bezier paths to convert lines to pictures.

I didn't find a way to create an *eraser*.

Do you have any ideas?

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];

    CGContextRef aRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    aPath.lineWidth = 5;
    [aPath stroke];
    [[[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0] setStroke];
    bPath.lineWidth = 5;
    [bPath stroke];
   movesss= CGBitmapContextCreateImage(aRef);
    if (movesss==NULL) {
        NSLog(@"null =(");
    }
}

-(void)moveTo:(CGPoint)pos {
    if(del){
        [bPath moveToPoint:pos];
    }
    else{
        [aPath moveToPoint:pos];
    }
}

-(void)cret{
    aPath=[[UIBezierPath bezierPath] retain];
    bPath=[[UIBezierPath bezierPath] retain];
    del=NO;
}

-(void)lineTo:(CGPoint)pos {
    if(del){
        [bPath addLineToPoint:pos];
    }
    else{
        [aPath addLineToPoint:pos];
    }
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

-(void)imgf{
    UIImage *imageToSave=[[UIImage imageWithCGImage:movesss] retain];

   UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageToSave, nil, nil, nil);
    UIImageView *trew=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[self frame]];
    [trew setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    [trew setImage:imageToSave];
    [self addSubview:trew];
}

-(void)swittch{
    del=!del;
}
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement an eraser as a pen that paints with a fully transparent color (set alpha to zero). [UIColor](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html) possesses a "alpha" parameter, that can be set at creation with colorWithAlphaComponent: for example.

Or just use `UIColor * color = [UIColor clearColor];`

EDIT:

I thought painting with clearColor would replace the pixels with clear pixels. It was dumb reasoning since painting several times with alpha-ed colors would  not work properly if it were the case.

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522594/how-to-erase-image-with-touch), transparent colors don't work for that purpose. You need to know your background color and paint with it. If your background color is "transparent"... I'm at a loss.

Comment: I followed your advice, but it doesn't work: lines are still black.

Comment: Thank you for the link. My background color is transparent. I just needed to change blend mode like that: CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGBlendModeCopy);

Answer (score 1):

Painting with the background color will work as an eraser.